# Performance/load test using REST Assured?

Tags: performance, java, load-testing

I am using Rest-Assured Java library to write API tier functional tests. We have built a whole product and are thoroughly enjoying it.
we also added the PERFORMANCE and LOAD TESTING into our pipeline using Jmeter but our road made is to test this performance/load via REST Assured.
Ideal scenario will be that somehow we are able to do both these testings using REST Assured only. I have read many places that thats not possible.

In that case, is there any way we can build on top of our current RESTAssured based framework and leverage same API calls/scripts to do performance/Load testing?
Maybe someone has figured out a way to use it with Load some tools  which allows you to run Selenium scripts directly on load generators.
If someone has found a way please let me know it will be highly beneficial to us.

If not please point out some of the best Java based open source tools for performance and load testing.

Answer (score 1):

you may be able to pass the REST-Assured tests to locust (https://locust.io/) for performance testing